# how to display two values in pie chart

Tags: ios, core-plot, pie-chart

I'm a newbie. I have a `NSObject` class named `dailyPortfolioPrices` and in interface file i declared 3 properties

In **dailyPortfolioPrices.h**

```
@interface dailyPortfolioPrices : NSObject 

@property (nonatomic, weak) NSDecimalNumber *num1;

@property (nonatomic, weak) NSDecimalNumber *num2;

@property (nonatomic, weak) NSDecimalNumber *num3;
```

In **dailyPortfolioPrices.m** file

I synthesized the above declared properties. I created an `UIViewController` class named `PageContentViewController` for displaying the `graph`.

**In PageContentViewController.m** file's `voidDidAppear` I declared the values for `dailyPortfolioPrices` like

```
dailyPortfolioPrices *dailyPortfolioPrices1 = [dailyPortfolioPrices new];
dailyPortfolioPrices1.num1 = @"586.13";
dailyPortfolioPrices1.num2 = @"606.53";
dailyPortfolioPrices1.num3 = @"32.03";


dailyPortfolioPrices *dailyPortfolioPrices2 = [dailyPortfolioPrices new];
dailyPortfolioPrices2.num1 = @"426.13";
dailyPortfolioPrices2.num2 = @"506.53";
dailyPortfolioPrices2.num3 = @"22.03";


dailyPortfolio = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: dailyPortfolioPrices1, dailyPortfolioPrices2, nil];
```

and did the codings as

![enter image description here][2]

*For Calculating the Percentage Value*

```
NSDecimalNumber *price = [dailyPortfolio objectAtIndex:index];

NSDecimalNumber *percent = [price decimalNumberByDividingBy:portfolioSum];
```

*For Setting up display label*

```
NSString *labelValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%0.2f USD (%0.1f %%)", [price floatValue], ([percent floatValue] * 100.0f)];
```

*Create and return layer with label text*

```
return [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:labelValue style:labelText]; }

-(NSString *)legendTitleForPieChart:(CPTPieChart *)pieChart recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

    if (index < [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] tickerSymbols] count]) {

        return [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] tickerSymbols] objectAtIndex:index]; 

        }

    return @"N/A"; 
}
```

But my graph is not showing any data in it. Can anybody tell where I made mistake. I want to display the `pie chart` in `UIViewController` using the `index`

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0):

[image]

But... why ?

You compare your field to a constant of something totally different, therefore I'm quite sure `numberForPlot` always return 0.

==========

[image]

Again, why ?

1. `labelText` is unused here
2. you return a decimal number when you need to return a `CPTLayer`

I don't know what you expect from this... I don't mean to be rude, but it seems you have no idea what you're doing.

Comment: can u tell how could i change that

Comment: remove the if around your return

Comment: i removed that one but my graph is not showing any values

Comment: Actually labelText is to represent each individual prices

Comment: Doesn't change it's unused and that you return something else than what you need to return.

Comment: i used the labelText here  return [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:labelValue style:labelText]

Comment: Yes but your code won't go that far, you already return something else before

Comment: can u tell me is there any method or keyword for combing 3 float values into one NSDecimaNumber

Comment: Price1 = price.num1;
Price2 = price.num2;
Price3 = price.num3;
        
        float f1 = [Price1 floatValue];
        float f2 = [Price2 floatValue];
        float f3 = [Price3 floatValue];   i need to combine these f1,f2,f3 values to "Price" of NSDecimalNumber type

Comment: Make a new question bro

Answer (score 0):

`-numberForPlot:field:recordIndex:` must return a number (or `nil`). The `dailyPortfolio` array contains something else.